# How to read and change series numbers in columns SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to manipulate a column in SSIS which looks like below after i removed unwanted rows with derived column and conditional split in my data flow task. The source for this is a flatfile.

XXX008001161022061116030S1TVCO3057
XXX008002161022061146015S1PUAG1523
XXX009001161022063116030S1DVLD3002
XXX009002161022063146030S1TVCO3057
XXX009003161022063216015S1PUAG1523
XXX010001161022065059030S1MVMA3020
XXX010002161022065129030S1TVCO3057
XXX01000316102206515901551PPE01504

The first three numbers from the left (starting with "008" first row) represent a series, and the next three ("001") represent another number within the series. what i need is to change all of the first three numbers starting from "001" to the end.

The desired reslut would thus look like:

XXX001001161022061116030S1TVCO3057
XXX001002161022061146015S1PUAG1523
XXX002001161022063116030S1DVLD3002
XXX002002161022063146030S1TVCO3057
XXX002003161022063216015S1PUAG1523
XXX003001161022065059030S1MVMA3020
XXX003002161022065129030S1TVCO3057
XXX00300316102206515901551PPE01504
...

My potential solution would be to load the file to a temporary database table and query it with SQL from there, but i am trying to avoid this.

The final destination is a flatfile.

Does anybody have any ideas how to pull this off in SSIS? Other solutions are appreciated also.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you manipulate the data with SQL code before sending it to your output? I'm thinking `RANK()` and `substring` to apply the changes?

Comment: I am wondering where i should send the data to be able to query it without creating a database? any ideas?

Comment: Since you need to know what the 'prior row' is ,the only way to do this in SSIS is with a script transformation or a custom component. Or you could use a staging table, which I recommend over building complex logic inside SSIS

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use the staging table approach and use windows functions to accomplish this.  I could see a use case if SSIS was on another machine than the database engine and there was a need to offload the processing to the SSIS box.

In that case I would create a script transformation.  You can process each row and make the necessary changes before passing the row to the output.  You can use C# or VB.

There are many examples out there.  Here is MSDN article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136114.aspx